# Bootstrap datetimepicker not appearing in correct place

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have a textbox with a bootstrap datetimepicker to select a date. The issue is the pop-up is not in the expected location.

[image: See the pop-up is way over to the left]

See the pop-up is way over to the left rather than where the text box is. Here is the code snipit..

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Release Date</label>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, new { @id = "datepicker", @name = "date" })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Date)
</div>
```

and the javascript..

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datetimepicker({
        format: "MM/DD/YYYY"
    });
});
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Why the pop-up seems to think the text box is in another location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding a div around it with custom styling. It turns out the issue was caused because the datetimepicker was snapping to the label instead of the textbox.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Release Date</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left:0px">
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, new { @id = "datepicker" })
      </div>
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Date)
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have query installed and linked in your html, you could do this:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Im not sure on datetimepicker, I have used date picker and it works..

Try that(erase your code and put that in the div (or maybe the div is messing it up and you may want to put it outside of the div) and see if it works

For more info visit this: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ (Which I am sure you have but nevertheless I thought of sharing it for other people)

Comment: The bootstrap I have does not know what datepicker is, only datetimepicker.

Comment: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>    Download jqquery and jquery ui from the link i gave you they xplain... I've used that one and it works.. plus it works on all browsers including IE